# How to name uploaded image files with PHP?

Tags: php, counter, uploading

I would like to change the code on my php uploading page so it uploaded photos with sequential numbering 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg... 9999999.jpg

I want to name images in an ascending order starting with 1 and going to infinity.

I don't want any images to be over written and I think a counter can be used for this, but i'm unaware of how to code it properly.

Uploaded images are stored in two directories. 1. original file 2. thumbnail

```
$DestinationDirectory    = 'user-uploads/'; //original file
    $DestinationDirectorytn  = 'user-uploads-thumbnails/'; //original file thumbnail
```

Currently it names the file by the  `time()` function

```
// current time value, will be added as the new image name
    $CurrentTime    = time(); 

//Construct a new image name (time) for our new image.
    $NewImageName = $CurrentTime.'.'.$ImageExt;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$directory = "user-uploads/";
$filecount = count(glob($directory . "*"))+1;
//Construct a new image name (time) for our new image.
$NewImageName = $filecount.'.'.$ImageExt;
```

Comment: if you are looking for particular image extension, change the wild card * to *.jpg or *.png as example

Comment: This is going to work, but the only problem im having is each upload is over writing the file before, so i'm never adding any additional files.

I just need to be able to at +1 to the file count...

how can I add 1 to the count result?

Comment: Ok I am editing my answer. It will be with +1 count. Try it now. Select is as your answer, if it works too :)

Answer (score 2):

You can count the files in directory and increment the value for to name of file.

The link have example: http://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/php-count-files-in-a-directory/

After that count the files, you set the name of file: concat value with name.

Thanks

But have many other ways.